# End-to-End Testing EmberJS using Selenium WebDriverJS

Tags: ember.js

We're starting to think about using an approach similar to Protractor to allow writing end-to-end acceptance tests in Node that use the Selenium WebDriverJS bindings. From looking through the Protractor guides/source, I've noticed that angular directly exposes a way to know that all timers/events/pending updates have been flushed and the application is back in steady state. is there an official way to do the same with ember?

Answer (score 1):

`ember-testing`’s [wait helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/#toc_wait-helpers)

> will wait for all preceding asynchronous helpers to complete prior to progressing forward.

Cory Forsyth’s [blog post on this topic](http://coryforsyth.com/2014/07/10/demystifing-ember-async-testing/) is helpful for explaining how this works in more detail.

You can [register your own test helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/test-helpers/#toc_custom-test-helpers) if the built in ones aren’t adequate.